# RESTEasy cannot call my annotated method on a scala class

Tags: scala, resteasy

Trying to implement a JAX-RS resource in Scala.  My Java version of this has the following type signature:

```
@GET
@Path(value="echoold")
@Produces("application/json")
public Map<String,Object> get(
        @QueryParam("param") String param,
        @QueryParam("asOf") @DefaultValue(NOW) DateWrapper asOf,
        @QueryParam("httpError") @DefaultValue("200") int httpError,
        @QueryParam("httpErrorMessage") @DefaultValue("") String httpErrorMessage,
        @QueryParam("fail") @DefaultValue("false") boolean fail) {
```

The Scala version is thus:

```
@GET
@Path(value="echo")
@Produces(Array("application/json"))
def get() = {
        @QueryParam("param") param:String,
        @QueryParam("asOf") @DefaultValue(NOW) asOf:DateWrapper,
        @QueryParam("httpError") @DefaultValue("200") httpError:java.lang.Integer,
        @QueryParam("httpErrorMessage") @DefaultValue("") httpErrorMessage:String,
        @QueryParam("fail") @DefaultValue("false") fail:java.lang.Boolean):java.util.Map[String,Object] = {
```

When I start up my application, I get this strange error from RESTEasy (which I've formatted for readability):

```
org.jboss.resteasy.spi.InternalServerErrorException: 
    Bad arguments passed to 
        public java.util.Map opower.api.endpoint.echo.Echo.get(java.lang.String,
                                                               opower.api.support.DateWrapper,
                                                               java.lang.Integer,
                                                               java.lang.String,
                                                               java.lang.Boolean)  
        ( java.lang.String someValue, 
          opower.api.support.DateWrapper opower.api.support.DateWrapper@28a34522, 
          java.lang.Integer 400, 
          java.lang.String This is the message, 
          java.lang.Boolean false )
```

The underlying exception is:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:140)
```

Now, this class is configured via Spring, so it *could* be some crazy proxy class and it's getting messed up, but has anyone else seen something like this?

(If you don't know what RESTEasy/JAX-RS is doing, basically the container (RESTEasy) finds methods on classes that have those annotations on them, and then calls them when certain URL endpoints are hit)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same with Spring/Scala and @Transactional method annotation.

needed to change proxy-target-class in

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager" 
          mode="proxy" proxy-target-class="true"/>
```

Default value for proxy-target-class is false. It requires cglib in classpath.

I guess mode="acpectj" might also work (didn't try)